# Two singletons instances with dependency injection (Google Guice)

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am working on a project using Depedency injection Google Guice Framework.

It's possible to bind a class with the singleton scope, in Guice as:

```
bind(Foo.class).to(FooImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

If `FooImpl` class is itself a real singleton class as:

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo{
    public static final FooImpl INSTANCE = new FooImpl();
    public static FooImpl getInstance(){...}
    // ...
}
```

or

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo{
    private FooImpl instance = null;

    private FooImpl(){...}
    public static FooImpl getInstance(){
         if(instance == null)
             instance = new FooImpl();
         return FooImpl();
         // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

So, It's could be possible to declare two singletons in the project, the first one declared by Guice and the second one by the `getInstance()` traditionnal way.

Google Guice can also bind Interfaces to particular instance with the `toInstance()` method.

So, instead binding with the Singleton scope, shouln't be a better way to bind Singleton, in Java with this declaration:

```
bind(Foo.class).toInstance(FooImpl.getInstance());
```

instead of the first one? Is it more secure? Is it possible to have two singletons instances in that way?

What's the best way for declaring singletons with Google Guice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first approach you suggest is preferred:

```
bind(Foo.class).to(FooImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

This allows Guice to perform dependency injection in `FooImpl` as needed. This is *not* possible when manually binding to an instance using `toInstance()` as in your last suggestion.

Finally, the Singleton design pattern [is an anti-pattern for many reasons](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/25/root-cause-of-singletons/). Note that this refers to the implementation using `getInstance()` and so on; having a single instance of a class for the lifetime of your app (like objects in Guice's `SINGLETON` scope) is *not* bad by any means.

Also see [Guice's page on scopes](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes) for some usage guidelines of the singleton scope.

Comment: I know Singleton is an anti-pattern, but I am not the initial code designer, so I have to work with it!

Comment: But, using the first way, it's possible that someone by error, forget about dependency injection and create the singleton instance with the new.. So we sould have, in that case, two singletons instance which is a problem (in my project, by example)

Comment: Normally, you would limit the visibility of the implementation (`FooImpl`) to package private or so. Because you're right: Users should not create instances themselves. See [this link on keeping constructors hidden](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/KeepConstructorsHidden). If you're stuck with `FooImpl` as it is, you're already beyond the best solution. I suppose binding the instance (your last suggestion) would be the second-best.